# Total Import permission denied

Tags: import, opencart, permission-denied, user-permissions

When I try to access my import tool for products `Tools->Total Import Pro` a message appears:

> You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator

I tried to go to `system->users->users groups->administrator->Modify Permission`
but I can't find the permission for TotalI mport.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you search the module inside **Access Permission:** and also **Modify Permission:** . Normally the module name will start with `module/your_module_name`.

If still cannot you can try to upload again(*maybe some files is missing*) or contact the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue Daniel.

Double check that all the files associated with the Export / Import tool are installed correctly. If the controller file is missing the system won't show it in the permissions list.

If the files were not upload, you can make it manually via FTP. I've done that and it worked for me.

After you've done that, make sure you give permission to admin to use the tool. Go to System > User Group > Admin and give access and modify permission to tool/export_import

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Users > Users groups
Edit the Group Administrator and make sure you are logging in as administrator

There are two boxes 
- Access Permission
- Modify Permission

You need to check to the checkbox 'tool/export_import' in both "Access permission" and "Modify permission". Is your case is Modify permission